# At what slope angle does walking uphill become more energy-efficient than cycling?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, everyday-life, biology

At what angle does walking uphill become more energy-efficient than cycling?
To me cycling uphill feels harder than walking uphill, so I wonder at what slope-angle this happens.

Two other ways to put this question:

- At what angle does walking uphill burn more calories than cycling uphill?
- At what angle does walking uphill feel "harder" than cycling uphill?

Comment: I believe this depends greatly on what gearing is available on the bike and how good the balance of the cyclist is.

Comment: It also depends on the road ,scientifically friction